# How to determine which promise throws error (in a promise chain)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How can I determine which of the three promises caused the error?

The code below is pseudo, but in my actual code I am working with third-party libraries (Stripe and Firebase) and therefore I cannot modify the actual Promises themselves.

I thought that I could check to see if the `error` argument in the `catch` contains a specific value (e.g. in Stripe there's a very detailed error object), but surely there must be a better way.

```
return async.func.one.doIt()
  .then(() => {
    return async.func.two.doIt();
  })
  .then(() => {
    return async.func.three.doIt();
  })
  .then(() => {
    return { success: true };
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // How do I know which 'then' caused
    // the catch to invoke?
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put '.catch' between each '.then' method to catch error. It should catch closest error that was thrown by any of previous promises, up to next '.catch' method.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code to this 
    `return func.one.doIt()
          .then(() => {
            return async.func.two.doIt().then(() => {
              return async.func.three.doIt().then(() => {
                return { success: true };
              }).catch((error) => {
                // How do I know which 'then' caused
                // the catch to invoke?
              });;
            }).catch((error) => {
              // How do I know which 'then' caused
              // the catch to invoke?
            });
          }).catch((error) => {
            // How do I know which 'then' caused
            // the catch to invoke?
          });`